# Grails 2.3.6 doesn't like going to the Jersey Core

Tags: grails, jersey, dependency-management, maven-central

My Grails 2.3.6 app transitively depends on `jersey-core-1.18.1`. In my `BuildConfig` I have the following repositories closure:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

When I do a `grails run-app` I get:

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-core:jar:1.18.1
```

**Why?** What do I need to add to fix this error and allow Grails to "find" Jersey Core?

Comment: Why the downvote without an explanation? This isn't a dupe, is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and there really isn't a way to *show research* with this question: I've looked in all the typical repos for this JAR. Downvoting won't make this problem simply disappear or go away!!!

Comment: "Maybe if we just downvote any questions that point out shortcoming or bugs in our technologies, the unwashed masses will not notice."

Comment: Searching Maven Central (http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|jersey-core) shows ```com.sun.jersey``` as the ```GroupId```.